# Compiling ffmpeg: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg using this guide https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#FFmpeg

Everything goes just fine, until I got to compile ffmpeg. Here is the error:

```
In file included from fftools/ffmpeg.c:43:0:
./libavformat/avformat.h:877:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^
LD      ffmpeg_g
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault],
core dumped
compilation terminated.
Makefile:107: recipe for target 'ffmpeg_g' failed
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

I installing it in linux subsystem on win10 v1709 build 16299.431

couldnt find anything on it. I'm quite new to compilation, also.